# Видео фон блока Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, background

Как вместо картинки поставить видеофон? (Wordpress).`

```html
 <header class="main_head main_color_bg" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/bg.jpg" data-z-index="1" data-position="bottom center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <button class="toggle_menu">
                        <span class="sandwich">
                          <span class="sw-topper"></span>
                          <span class="sw-bottom"></span>
                          <span class="sw-footer"></span>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                    <nav class="top_menu">
                        <div class="logo_container">
                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#about" rel="m_PageScroll2id">About me</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#resume" rel="m_PageScroll2id">Resume</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#portfolio" rel="m_PageScroll2id">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contacts" rel="m_PageScroll2id">Contacts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
```

Что нужно заменить в хедере, дабы ничего лишнего не задеть.

Answer (score 1):

Да ничего заменять не нужно, если использовать, например плагин Vide ([документация](http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/)), оставляем все как есть, подключаем jquery и сам плагин Vide, немного магии js и получаем:

```js
$(function() {
  $("header").vide('http://falbar.ru/uploads/storage/demos/2014/09/OTRhMDY4Z/ocean.mp4', {
    volume: 1, // звук
    playbackRate: 1, // скорость воспроизведения
    muted: true, // отключен ли звук
    loop: true, // закцикливание
    autoplay: true, // автовоспроизведение
    position: "50% 50%" // выравнивание
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

  <script src="http://falbar.ru/uploads/storage/demos/2014/09/OTRhMDY4Z/jquery.vide.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="main_head main_color_bg" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/bg.jpg" data-z-index="1" data-position="bottom center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <button class="toggle_menu">
            <span class="sandwich">
                          <span class="sw-topper"></span>
            <span class="sw-bottom"></span>
            <span class="sw-footer"></span>
            </span>
          </button>
          <nav class="top_menu">
            <div class="logo_container">
              <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
            </div>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#about" rel="m_PageScroll2id">About me</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#resume" rel="m_PageScroll2id">Resume</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#portfolio" rel="m_PageScroll2id">Portfolio</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#contacts" rel="m_PageScroll2id">Contacts</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```